# converting elf32--bigarm to motorolla s19

Tags: gcc, arm, elf

i want to convert an elf32-bigarm to motorolla s19 using binutil objcopy of codesourcery toolchain as:

```
    copy Sample.elf Sample.s19

    arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe -O srec Sample.s19
```

when i convert the file it converts it automatically to little endian. i.e.

```
0x12345678 to 0x78563412
```

how can i solve this problem.

i have seen the dump of elf and it is in correct endianness. while s19 file has incorrect ordering.

Comment: Are you sure you need that in big endian? Does the program that makes use of the s19 file work in big-endian?

Comment: according to documentation it does not change the endianness of elf

Comment: Please show the dump extracts that lead you believe the endian has swapped. Is there any other evidence?

Comment: i was using incorrect switch of --be8 while linking. problem solved. thnx